# How to set $PATH to node on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, node.js

The Autoprefixer plugin in Sublime Text 3 show this error about node.js not found in `$PATH`

[image: Sublime Text Autoprefixer error]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What is auto prefix here?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like you are using the [Autoprefixer plugin for Sublime Text 3](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer) in Windows 10.

You need to make sure you have [node.js installed for Windows](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). The node.js should automatically add `node.exe` to your `PATH`

[image: node.js installer]

If it doesn't, manually add `node.exe` into the System `PATH` variable

[image: Add system PATH in Windows]